# UseEffect not triggering when used with MaterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, use-effect

This is my first time using this platform to ask questions so please pardon me if my question does not seem well developed.

**brief introduction**

what I am trying to achieve is a dynamic Tab navigator, whereby the number of tabs changes depending on the number of elements in an array where this array changes in the number of elements over time, i.e :

```
{
  userIds : [1,2,3,4,5,6]
}
```

will render a tab navigator with 6 tabs

I am using react-redux for managing state and I have been following this tutorial on youtube just for your information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9boMnm5X9ak&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwheJHvseC3I0HuYI2f46oAK

**context**

in the main code snippet the action `FetchMonthlyTransIdAct()` is being dispatched, this consist of 2 actions being dispatched in order :

`RequestMonthlyTransaction` → `FetchSuccess` or `FetchFail`

(as per mentioned in FetchMonthlyTransIdAct.js, ) the initial state is as follows and the changes each action does :

```
{
  loading : false
  Id : []
  error : ''
}
```

```
{
  loading : true //when RequestMonthlyTransaction is dispatched
  Id : []
  error : ''
}
```

```
{
  loading : false // When FetchSuccess is dispatched after RequestMonthlyTransaction
  Id : [1,2,3,4,5,6]// When FetchSuccess is dispacthed after RequestMonthlyTransaction
  error : ''
}
```

```
{
  loading : false //when FetchFail is dispacthed after RequestMonthlyTransaction
  Id : []
  error : 'some error message here' //when FetchFail is dispatched after RequestMonthlyTransaction
}
```

**problem**

so the problem that I am currently facing is that `useEffect` does not seem to trigger when I am rendering components with `navigationContainer`/ `tab.navigator`

here is the snippet of my code, I have narrowed down the source of the problem between asterisks

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    userData: state.MonthlyEntry
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    FetchMonthlyTransId: () => dispatch(FetchMonthlyTransIdAct())
  }
}

const EntryTabNavigator = ({userData, FetchMonthlyTransId}) => {

  useEffect (() => {
        FetchMonthlyTransId()
  }, [])
    console.log(userData.Id)

    if (userData.loading || userData.error != '') {
        return <View/>

    } else {
        return( 
             **************************************************************************************
             <NavigationContainer independent = {true}>
                <Tab.Navigator swipeEnabled = {true} tabBarOptions = {{scrollEnabled:true, tabStyle:{width:120}}}>
                    {userData.Id.map((data) => {return (<Tab.Screen key = {data.toString()} name = {data.toString()} component = {MonthlyTransactions} initialParams={{id:data.toString()}}/>)})}
                </Tab.Navigator>
             </NavigationContainer>
             **************************************************************************************
        )
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EntryTabNaviga
```

the error message simply that there was no screen for tab navigator to render (due to `userData.Id` being an empty array when it should not)

based on the `console.log(userData.Id)`

the expected output should be `Array [1,2,3,4,5,6]`
but the actual output was `Array []` which indicates that the `useEffect` was not triggered

I have tried replacing the snippet of code between the astericks with 
`<View><Text>{userData.Id}</Text><View>` and it was able to render as expected (returning a screen with the string representation of the array as the text), hence leading me to identify that the code snippet between the astericks is the problematic portion.  I have also tried adding a `console.log` statement within `useEffect` and it does not output anything into the console when I have the code snippet in asterisks, however it does output into the console when I replaced the snippet of code between the astericks with `<View><Text>{userData.Id}</Text><View>`

should there be a similar problem to this that has already been asnwered, it would be much apppreciated if you could direct me to it, it would also be great if you could point me to resources to improve my knowledge with redux (prefreably beginner friendly) ! additional reference code (reducer and action) is below

Thank you in advance

**FetchMonthlyTransIdAct.js**

```
const requestMonthlyTransaction = () => {
  return {
    type: "REQUEST_MONTHLY_TRANSACTION",
  }
}

const fetchSucess = (ids) => {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_SUCCESS",
    payload: ids,
  }
}

const fetchFail = (error) => {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_FAILURE",
    payload: error,
  }
}

export const FetchMonthlyTransIdAct = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestMonthlyTransaction())
    async function getId() {
      return require('../../data/DummyId.js').id //returns [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    }
    getId().then(
      id => dispatch(fetchSucess(id))
    ).catch(
      error => dispatch(fetchFail(error))
    )

  }
}
```

**FetchMonthlyTransIdRed.js**

```
const initialState = {
  loading:false,
  Id : [],
  error:''
}

const FetchMonthlyTransactionIdRed = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type){
    case "REQUEST_MONTHLY_TRANSACTION":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      }

    case "FETCH_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        Id: action.payload
      }

    case "FETCH_FAILURE":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload
      }
    default: return state;
  }
}


export default FetchMonthlyTransactionIdRed;
```

Comment: What are the actions that are dispatched and what are the changes they cause to the state? It would help if you could indicate at what step it goes wrong.

Comment: @HMR I have edited the question see **Context**. for indicating at what step goes wrong, I was not able to identify the exact step, I was only able to narrow the source of the problem as per highlighted in **problem**

Comment: `so the problem that I am currently facing is that useEffect does not seem to trigger` Then what is dispatching all these actions? And `if (userData.loading) {` loading is false when there is an error but Id will be an empty array.

Comment: it would be easy to debug your code if you create a codesanbox demo of the relevant code and share the link

Comment: alright, will take note and work on it thank you for the suggestion! @Yousaf

Answer (score 0):

after much tinkering, I manage to find a solution (or a workaround rather) to the problem. which is to add an initial element in the array of the `Id` attribute in the initial state in **FetchMonthlyTransIdRed.js**, that will allow the first render of the navigation component to occur without issues, and subsequently in the next re-render when `FetchMonthlyTransId` is dispatched `Id` is then updated with the array that I have imported

Answer (score 0):

Use React Navigation's [`useFocusEffect`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/), e.g.:

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Profile({ userId }) {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const unsubscribe = API.subscribe(userId, user => setUser(user));
      return () => unsubscribe();
    }, [userId])
  );

  return <ProfileContent user={user} />;
}
```